# PHP - date function to go back in time week by week for a year

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have the following code:

```
$last_week_start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("monday last week"));
$last_week_end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("sunday last week"));

for($i=52;$i>0;$i--){
    //do stuff with the dates for this week

    $last_week_start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($last_week_start,"-7 days"));
    $last_week_end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($last_week_end,"-7 days"));
}
```

The original two dates it gives me are correct but when I try to jump back a week I get an error saying `A non well formed numeric value encountered`.

I am not sure why this is happening or how I should fix this, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: please share your expected output.

Comment: Because `strotime` expects the date string in the first argument and in the second argument a timestamp as base time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime(time, now); Required. Specifies a date/time string`

use this way to get currect output

`date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-7 days",strtotime($last_week_start)))`

```
<?PHP
    $last_week_start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("monday last week"));
    $last_week_end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("sunday last week"));
    echo $last_week_start." ".$last_week_end;
    for($i=52;$i>0;$i--){
        //do stuff with the dates for this week
    
        $last_week_start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-7 days",strtotime($last_week_start)));
        $last_week_end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-7 days", strtotime($last_week_end)));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `strotime` expects a date string in the first argument and in the second argument a timestamp as base time.

You can change your code to use the `DateTime` object and manipulate the date on this.

```
<?php
$last_week_start = new \DateTime("monday last week");
$last_week_end = new \DateTime("sunday last week");

for($i=52;$i>0;$i--){
    //do stuff with the dates for this week

    $last_week_start->modify("-7 days");
    $last_week_end->modify("-7 days");
    $last_week_start_formatted = $last_week_start->format("Y-m-d");
    $last_week_end_formatted = $last_week_end->format("Y-m-d");
}
```